# Any good tips / tutorials to record audio / video feeds?

Tags: c#, .net

As the question states... I been wanting a way to record audio for sure from internet radio stations forever now, and quite possibly external video feeds (cameras, maybe A/V input...).

Anyone got any good tutorials, or resources? I tried to ask google a couple times but not sure how to word the Q.

Comment: A sample project    http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34663/DirectShow-Examples-for-Using-SampleGrabber-for-Gr

Answer (score 1):

One of the most popular libraries for multimedia with C# is [DirectShow.NET](http://sourceforge.net/projects/directshownet/). It comes with [samples](http://sourceforge.net/projects/directshownet/files/DirectShowSamples/2010-February/), one of which is related to recording. It might be a good starting point.

> Samples\Capture\CapWMV Capture from video capture devices to WMV
>   files.